# Install firefox os apps available on Marketplace using App Manager

Tags: manifest, firefox-os

I am trying to install App using App Manager in Firefox OS device. But my problem is I am unable to push any of the apps which are published on MarketPlace. It show that

```
The webapp manifest isn't a valid JSON file: SyntaxError: JSON.parse:
unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data at: 
https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/pacman-canvas can't be opened
```

So can anyone suggest some way to push the app to my device using App Manager only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy. On the Marketplace page (in Firefox desktop) open the marketplace page for the app. Then open Devtools and select the Debugger. In the debugger, break in file iframe-installer.html, on this line:

```
installPackage(e);
```

Now click the 'Free' button, the debugger will break on this line. In the console you now type:

```
e.data.data.product.manifest_url
```

This will give you a URL. If the URL is located at someone else's webserver (like Pacman), e.g. `http://pacman.platzh1rsch.ch/pacman-canvas.webapp`, you can (in the App Manager) click 'Add hosted app' and paste the URL. However you will need internet on the phone the first time you use the app (because its hosted app).

If the URL is a Mozilla URL (`https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/etc.`), you can open the link in your browser. Open the file. You now have a JSON file in which you need to look for the `package_path` key. F.e. for [Recorder](https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/recorder) it's

```
"package_path": "https://marketplace.firefox.com/downloads/file/258677/recorder-1.1.zip"
```

You can now download this ZIP file, unzip it in a folder, and add the folder as a Packaged app.

Answer (score 0):

For apps in the marketplace, you best solution for getting them on the phone is to just use the marketplace app.  That said if you own the app in the marketplace you should be able to look at the manifest url of the app using the edit listing marketplace button.  If this is a hosted app you can you use this manifest url in the add hosted app entry box within the app manager to add it and then push it to phone.  On another note you can debug the system apps by using the procedure described here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Using_the_App_Manager#Debugging_Certified_Apps

Comment: Actually I am looking for a way to run few games on my device, as my I am unable to connect to Internet through it. So I was hoping that if there is any way to install few games on it, as we do it one Android using adb install.